# How to update the "MajorVersionLimit" property using SOAP or REST API?

Tags: development, sharepoint-server, rest, soap

I'm working on a tool that will help my team in creating large numbers of libraries on a given site. Unfortunately, I can use only SOAP/REST interface to perform needed actions. I developed a simple form that contains of a textbox to provide SP site's URL and a DataGridView with columns: Name, Descritpion, FeatureID and Template to enter the library data.

So here is the code:

```
private void addLibraryList_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListsProd.Lists listReference = new ListsProd.Lists();
        string URL = siteUrl.Text;
        if (URL[URL.Length - 1].ToString() != "/")
        {
            URL += "/";
        }
        listReference.Url = URL + "_vti_bin/lists.asmx";
        listReference.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in libraryList.Rows)
        {
            if (row.Cells["name"].Value != null && row.Cells["description"].Value != null && row.Cells["featureId"].Value != null && row.Cells["template"].Value != null) 
            {
                string listName = row.Cells["name"].Value.ToString();
                string description = row.Cells["description"].Value.ToString();
                System.Guid featureId = new Guid(row.Cells["featureId"].Value.ToString());
                int templateId = Int32.Parse(row.Cells["template"].Value.ToString());
                XmlNode xmlResponse = listReference.AddListFromFeature(listName, description, featureId, templateId);
                XmlDocument xmlDoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
                XmlNode ndProperties = xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "List", "");
                XmlAttribute ndQuickLaunchAttrib = (XmlAttribute)xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Attribute, "OnQuickLaunch", "");
                ndQuickLaunchAttrib.Value = "True";
                ndProperties.Attributes.Append(ndQuickLaunchAttrib);
                XmlNode ndReturn = listReference.UpdateList(row.Cells["name"].Value.ToString(), ndProperties, null, null, null, null);
                row.Cells["status"].Value = "DONE";
            }
        }
        MessageBox.Show("All done!");

    }
```

I can successfully add libraries using this form but in some cases I also need to set the MajorVersionLimit to other value than in the list template.

I tried to pass that attribute directly to UpdateList method but it doesn't work. MajorVersionLimit isn't listed on the method's properties list: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.updatelist(v=office.12).aspx but the funny thing is, that "OnQuickLaunch" attribute isn't listed there either and it works perfectly.

So - is there any way to update the MajorVersionLimit attribute using SOAP or REST interface?

Answer (score 1):

The following JavaScript example shows how to update `SP.List.MajorVersionLimit` property via REST Interface:

```
var properties = {
  MajorVersionLimit: 50
};
updateList(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl,"Pages",properties)
.done(function()
{
    console.log('List has been updated');
})
.fail(function(error){
    console.log('An error occured while updating a list');
});
```

where

```
function executeJson(url,method,headers,payload) 
{
    method = method || 'GET';
    headers = headers || {};
    headers["Accept"] = "application/json;odata=verbose";
    if(method == "POST") {
        headers["X-RequestDigest"] = $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val();
    }      
    var ajaxOptions = 
    {       
       url: url,   
       type: method,  
       contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
       headers: headers
    };
    if (typeof payload != 'undefined') {
      ajaxOptions.data = JSON.stringify(payload);
    }  
    return $.ajax(ajaxOptions);
}


function updateList(webUrl,listTitle,properties){
    var url = webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('" + listTitle + "')";
    var payload = properties;
    payload["__metadata"] = { "type": "SP.List" };
    var headers = {
        "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE",
        "If-Match": "*"
    };
    return executeJson(url,'POST',headers,payload);              
}
```

> Note: have been verified against SharePoint Online

Comment: I missed one important information - I connect to SharePoint 2010. So unfortunately there is no "_api/web/lists" interface, just the old "_vti_bin/listdata.svc" which returns only list's items and no properties to modify... That's why I cannot use MERGE or PUT methods.